# How to work around "Something wicked happened resolving" errors

Tags: apache2

after this string in terminal - sudo apt-get install apache2 - it gives me errors

Failed to fetch http://archieve.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil
1_1.5.2-1_amd64.deb Something wicked happened resolving 'archieve.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No adress associated with hostname)

What to do ???

Comment: Use another mirror - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors

Answer (score 0):

This is to help people setup and install a LAMP (Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP) server in Ubuntu, including Apache 2, PHP 5 and MySQL 4.1 or 5.0 : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

I hope it be useful.
If it don't work you can use this way ( add repository:ppa ) :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ptn107/apache
```

then install apache :

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker
```

And to check it you can use:

```
apache2 -v
```

Comment: after sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ptn107/apache terminal tells me Please check that the PPA name or format is correct

Comment: is this your result ? :root@alcintraz:~# sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ptn107/apache
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ptn107/+archive/apache
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpzs8uez/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpzs8uez/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 1F621554 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpzs8uez/trustdb.gpg: trustdb ...

Comment: your error related to your connection with your cache ? check your source list: sources.list in this directory : /etc/apt/sources.list ... and ppa source list is in this directory: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/